# There's no cdqa in pypi

Tags: python, pypi

I'm trying to install cdqa but it seems like the library is missing from pypi. it shows this message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cdqa==1.3.9 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cdqa==1.3.9
```

anyone knows what happened and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project of cdpa(https://pypi.org/project/cdqa/) is 404 now. You can try install it from source code. Quote from the github as below:

```
git clone https://github.com/cdqa-suite/cdQA.git
cd cdQA
pip install -e .
```

Comment: I am getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 2962: character maps to <undefined>`